# Fixing this java tokenizer error in my code, trying to parse through text document for keywords frequency but stuck at this

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, keyword, tokenize

I created this input reader in my parser class Java, it counts 5 keywords' frequency in 5 text document files of HTML sources.

1) But first I have the following logic error:
Multiple markers at this line.
    - StringTokenizer cannot be resolved
     to a type
    - StringTokenizer cannot be resolved
     to a type

I have arrays cannot be resolved in my array list line.

2) If the error has been fixed, how do I make my parser read 5 documents at once?

Here is my main Java:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
public class TfIdfMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    }
}
```

Here is my document parser class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DocumentParser {

    private void doSomething(){
            [10];
            String x;
            int count = -1;
            while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                count++;
                x = str.nextToken();
                word[count] = x;
               System.out.println(count + ": " + word[count]);
            }

            System.out.println("---Frequency---");
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

                if ((!Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[i]))) {
                    unique[i] = word[i];
                }

                                  );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: comments wouldn't hurt

Comment: You could start by importing `java.util.StringTokenizer`.

Comment: And finish by doing an Array of String files and using a for loop.

Comment: @Compass hey thanks! can you please write an answer? I don't know how to fix the array error, I justa dded tokenizer.

Comment: @Zircon also sir how would I fix the array error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a set of multiple files:

```
String[] files = {"foo.txt", "bar.txt", "baz.txt"};

for(String file : files) {
    DocumentParser dp = new DocumentParser();
    dp.parseFiles(file);
    dp.getCosineMatrix();
}
```

Basically, define the array of files, then iterate using a for loop, creating a new DocParser each time. If you can reuse the DocParser with new files, then just move the DocumentParser declaration outside the for loop.

Comment: hey sir thank you so much for helping me! I still have one or things I want to fix in this code, I've been stuck on this for hours. You think I can email you? My email is firstjavapython on gmail. Since I can't post another question until another hour, and I don't know if you will be on later. My email is a temporary account so you won't worry about privacy. Please consider helping me if you have time, I'm too good with java. Thank you!

Comment: please consider help me! I'm fixing some other error now. and I can't post another question for like an hour. I don't know if you will on this later.

Comment: sir also I have new error in my main, Multiple markers at this line
 - Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an 
  explicit constructor
 - Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit 
  constructor

Comment: @danluo define a constructor and make it throw an exception